# AWS Hbase: Invalid method name: 'getTableNames'

Tags: python, hbase, happybase

I am using Hbase 0.94.18 on AWS EMR. I am planning to use HappyBase as it looks very promising. Unfortunately I faced this issue on the very first attempt:

```
conn = happybase.Connection(port=9200,compat='0.94')

conn.tables()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/happybase/connection.py", line 238, in tables
names = self.client.getTableNames()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/happybase/hbase/Hbase.py", line 818, in getTableNames
return self.recv_getTableNames()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/happybase/hbase/Hbase.py", line 833, in recv_getTableNames
raise x
thrift.Thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'getTableNames'
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the interface you're connecting to is a HBase Thrift1 service? It looks like a protocol incompatibility...

Comment: Its Thrift2 interface

Comment: there you have it. happybase uses thrift1.

Comment: Ahh okkay Thank you. I will start thrift1 server and try

Comment: Genius, I changed thrift version to 1 and it solved the problem

Comment: As of today, it seems that `happybase` is using thrift2: https://github.com/python-happybase/happybase/blob/master/requirements.txt#L2

Comment: nope, don't confuse hbase thrift api versioning with python client libraries for the thrift protocol

Answer (score 2):

When using "hbase thrift2 start -threadpool" I get the same error.

When using "thrift" (i.e. thrift 1) the error disappears.

This is caused by accessing the thrift 2 interface using happybase's thrift 1 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

hbase thrift 2 has delete the function.